# Docker - where are the src files for ADD and COPY?

Tags: docker, dockerfile, lamp, ubuntu-16.04

I am trying to learn Docker from other DockerFiles and and set up a **customised** development environment for my projects.

But from other DockerFiles, I don't understand - where are those `src` files coming from for `ADD` and `COPY`? How do I create them myself? What code should I put inside them?

For instance, [fauria/lamp](https://hub.docker.com/r/fauria/lamp/~/dockerfile/):

```
COPY run-lamp.sh /usr/sbin/
```

Where can I get this file or create it? What are the lines inside that file?

again, [nickistre/ubuntu-lamp](https://hub.docker.com/r/nickistre/ubuntu-lamp/~/dockerfile/):

```
ADD supervisord.conf /etc/
```

Where can I get a copy of it?

Another one, [linuxconfig/lamp](https://hub.docker.com/r/linuxconfig/lamp/~/dockerfile/):

```
# Include supervisor configuration
ADD supervisor-lamp.conf /etc/supervisor/conf.d/
ADD supervisord.conf /etc/supervisor/
```

`supervisor-lamp.conf` and `supervisord.conf`?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

When you run a `docker build .`, files in the folder `.` that are not included inside the `.dockerignore` file are sent to the Docker engine. From this context of files, docker performs the COPY or ADD commands.

With your first example, the Dockerfile is located in a [github repo](https://github.com/fauria/docker-lamp) (linked on the right side of the page on the Docker hub), and inside that repo is the `run-lamp.sh` script. Therefore if you're trying to reproduce the image, you would checkout the linked github repo and perform your build from within that folder.

Comment: You would checkout the repo on github if you're replicating the existing build environment. Then you run your `docker build` inside that folder. Or maybe I'm not understanding your question?

Comment: Ultimately, I would like to create my own scr files.

Comment: You simply create your own source files, in the same folder or subdirectory beside your Dockerfile. The build command sends the context to the engine, and the engine will import any files you request with the ADD/COPY commands.

Comment: `You simply create your own source files, in the same folder or subdirectory beside your Dockerfile.` I know this step, but what goes inside the files is what I am asking about.

Comment: for instance, https://github.com/fauria/docker-lamp/blob/master/run-lamp.sh probably is written based `some basic structure` elsewhere. Then this `basic structure` is what I am looking for.

Comment: Whatever content you need for your container. These files can be anything, there's no one answer or master structure for what you can put inside a container. If it's a supervisord config file, check out the supervisord site. If you're making a shell script for your entrypoint, then any shell scripting tutorial will point you the right way. With containers, the only gotchas are around the logic of running your command as pid 1, io, signal handling, and the likes.

Comment: Aww OK. Do I actually need those src files to run the container? Can I just ignore them? Will the container fail without them?

Comment: Images are built from Dockerfiles and a context (the full github repo). Docker hub is a repository of built images. Running a container pulls a built image and then executes it in an isolated space. So there's no need to get the Dockerfile or other source files if you want to run a container from an image, they've already been packaged and get downloaded with a pull.

Comment: Yes I understand that. What I really need is a customised image that suits me and I can change/ edit/ upgrade it myself - instead of relying on those from Docker hub.

Comment: Look into the usage of `FROM` in a Dockerfile. You'll want to point your image to be based on one that already exists on the docker hub.